# Count data in specific row on mysql table

Tags: mysql, math, count, counter

hi how can i count integers in specific column of mysql table?

```
+------------+--------+
| product_id | stores |
+------------+--------+
|     371374 |      1 |
|     283994 |      1 |
|     232191 |      2 |
|     131127 |      1 |
|     284000 |      1 |
|     371383 |      1 |
|         83 |      3 |
|     131156 |      1 |
|     371385 |      1 |
|     284004 |      1 |
+------------+--------+
```

i want to count all stores like 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT SUM(stores) FROM tablename`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(stores) 
  FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select sum(stores) from <tablename>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM( stores ) AS sum
FROM `table_name`
```